# Trying to texture a landscape with color ramp, but it won't work

Tags: texturing, materials, shader-nodes

I am trying to texture a landscape with a color ramp, because I don't know how else to put two textures on a landscape.

But for some reason it's not, separating between white and black.

[image: ColorRamp]

Comment: Sorry, what is the end result you're trying to accomplish? Are you looking for different brightness levels at different heights?

Comment: I'm trying to combine a rock and a grass texture.

Comment: So you're using the ColorRamp as a mix factor? Can you show a screenshot that shows the rest of your node setup? I don't think you need the Normal Node, for one thing. Also, is there some specific reason you're using Normal texture coordinates (as opposed to generated, object, or UV)?

Comment: Wait, I think, I get it, you're using the normal because you want the grass to show on the upward pointing faces, and the rock on the sides, correct? If so, use a SeparateXYZ Node (Z component) instead of a Normal Node.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. So I did ctrl shift T to view the the color ramp, and I must have clicked it twice because it was on alpha instead of color. Once I did ctrl shift T again to get it back on color it work like normal. Thanks for your help[image: Color Ramp works now]